# Add FeedBack Feature To Application

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to IOS programming so I'm not sure if this is a staple of programming or something complex, but I would like to add a feedback feature to my application. That is, I am thinking of having a button called "FeedBack", that, when the user clicks on it, redirects them to their native email application with the 'to' section already filled with my credentials. Any advice on how I can do that?

Comment: Use `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your information you cannot send mail from simulator so it gives error which handled here try the following code

```
 import Foundation
    import MessageUI
    import UIKit

    class test: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
            {
            sendEmail() 

            }        
            else
            {
                print("Mail services are not available")
                return
             }

        }

        func sendEmail() {      
            let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

            composeVC.setToRecipients(["youraddress@example.com"])
            composeVC.setSubject("Any subject!")
            composeVC.setMessageBody("this is your message body!", isHTML: false)
            // Present the view controller modally.
            self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                               didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {

            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. From your code, I understand that I have to create another View Controller in the Storyboard, is that correct? Or do I just implement it without a Storyboard counterpart?

Comment: No it is not necessary  to create  new controller 
You just need to implement delegate method  in viewcontroller from which you have  move to Mail application

Comment: Which delegate method would I use? Sorry, I am new to programming. Also, how to I call this only when a button is clicked?

Comment: Copy send mail and mailcompose from this code and put into your view controller don't forget to import messageui and mfmaildelegate

Comment: Thankyou. And about the button?

Comment: Call send mail function  from button click method

Comment: Thankyou, I will give this a try and let you know. I have marked your answer correct until I try it.

Comment: Hello, I am getting a warning for `func mailComposeController` reading "Instance method nearly matches optional requirement". Is that ok?

Comment: Hello, if the mail application is not installed on my phone, the application crashes. Is there any way to code against this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151666/discussion-between-jaydeep-vyas-and-m-i).

Comment: yes you can prevent this show in above code in viewdidload method you can check is mail is installed or not